# How to do reverse filtering in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am filtering the array

```
$filter('filter')($scope.model.data, {dataType: term });
```

But how to do reverse filtering
I want to exclude some data from displaying

```
$filter('filter')($scope.model.data, {dataType: 'wrongtype' }); // Exclude this type
```

Something like `$filter('excludefilter')($scope.model.data, {dataType: 'wrongtype' })`

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/jocane/3/edit?html,js,output

```
  $scope.filterd =   $filter('filter')($scope.allMyObjects, {name: '!rike' });
```